# In IntelliJ: Showing the return value from the method we just stepped out of

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, return-value

The article, [*Debugging Tutorial: Java Return Value, IntelliJ Jump to Line, and More*](https://dzone.com/articles/debugging-tutorial-java-return-value-intellij-jump), says:

> We can enable the "Show method return values" settings option in IntelliJ

Where is this setting?

And what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA's "Services" tool window.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Services tool window screengrab]

When you click on the gear icon on the left, you can see the "Show Method Return Values" option. It's unchecked by default.

It shows the return value of the last method call (relative to where the debugger cursor is) in the "Variables" panel on the right.